# My mouse sleeps and takes a while to wake up

Tags: mouse, 22.10, input-devices

I using a Dell Optiplex 790 and sometimes if I'm not using the mouse it "falls asleep" and won't work for a while.  It eventually wakes up but it can be as much as 10s before I get mouse function.  Is there anyway around that?  My computer is not sleeping when this happens.
I've tried using a PS/2 mouse and the same thing happens.  I've also tried other USB mouses to no effect. I'm pretty sure it's a software problem or deep hardware (not peripherals).

Comment: Don't know why I did that.  Fixed it.

Comment: I may have stumbled on the answer.  I had an episode of this problem when I loaded Steam so I decided to turn off auto loading Steam and reboot.  As it turned out I was loading steam from the steam interface and in the linux startup entry.  I think that caused my problem.  Going to turn this into an answer tomorrow if it works.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out I had Steam loading twice.  Once from the Steam interface and once from the Ubuntu interface  It seems they were fighting over the mouse and that caused the temporary hang that I described.
Anyways, be careful if you autoload programs to only use the Ubuntu interface or you might have problems like I did.